# isRTL.coffee library to determine if a text is of right-to-left direction

Tags: javascript, performance, coffeescript, i18n, unicode

I just wrote this tiny library called [isRTL.coffee](https://github.com/dhilipsiva/isRTL.coffee) to determine the direction of the text. Is there any better way of doing this?

```
rtlChars = '\u0600-\u06FF' # Arabic - Range

rtlChars += '\u0750-\u077F' # Arabic Supplement - Range

rtlChars += '\uFB50-\uFDFF' # Arabic Presentation Forms-A - Range

rtlChars += '\uFE70-\uFEFF' # Arabic Presentation Forms-B - Range

reRTL = new RegExp "^[#{rtlChars}]"

window.isRTL = (value) ->
    if value.match reRTL
        true
    else
        false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, it's possible to improve. You can simply do:

```
window.isRTL = (value) ->
    reRTL.test value
```

Another way to improve is the way you declare your special characters. Right now, it's confusing between the `=` and `+=`. Here is another way:

```
rtlChars = [
    '\u0600-\u06FF' # Arabic - Range
    '\u0750-\u077F' # Arabic Supplement - Range
    '\uFB50-\uFDFF' # Arabic Presentation Forms-A - Range
    '\uFE70-\uFEFF' # Arabic Presentation Forms-B - Range
].join("")

reRTL = new RegExp "^[#{rtlChars}]"
```

This way, adding a new character is simply adding a line in an array.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine, using `match` is not appropriate, not only you are discarding the match but the function will not return a boolean value, so `isRTL(...) === true` will never evaluates to `true`. It would be best to use `reRTL.test value` instead.

Comment: @plalx : Correction a string does not have a "test" method. match seems to be the way to go.

Comment: @dhilipsiva No, just call `test` on the regular `RegExp` instance rather than the string like I demonstrated in my previous comment.

Comment: @plalx I just feel so stupid sometimes :P Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

The real usefulness of such a library can only come from completeness. You should try to support all other RTL languages as well. Anybody can come up with a simple function to detect Arabic chars.

Also, what if the text contains a mix of languages, some RTL while others LTR. Your library would report any text containing at least one arabic character as RTL.

- One approach would be to report number of RTL chars v/s LTR chars.
- Another take would be to parse the text into sections, each labeled as RTL or LTR.

Comment: Removed the code samples, concentrating of the general talk.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Just scratching my own itch for now. Will make it better eventually. :)